# D3 - Append SVG inside SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have been trying to append a set of SVGs  inside SVG. So, in inside SVG, I want to  create a function to make plot. However, this doesn't work in the way I expected as the inside SVGs don't have the dimension according to my specification. So, I'd like to know what went wrong.

```
svg_g_g = svg_g.append("g")
                    .selectAll("g")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + xScale(d.key) + "," + lift + ")"
                    })
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.key) })
                    .attr("height", height)

                    .append("line")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d.key) })
                    .attr("y1", height-100)
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.key) + 50 } )
                    .attr("y2", height-100);
```

This is the output.
[image]

While if I bind data to g (without appending svg), the result looks more promising.

```
svg_g_g = svg_g.append("g");
        svg_g_g.selectAll("line")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("x1", function(d) { return xScale(d.key) })
                    .attr("y1", height-100)
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return xScale(d.key) + 50 } )
                    .attr("y2", height-100);
```

and this is the result. (notice: the lines were shown in this case)

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

**edit:** what I intended to do was I wanted to create a box-plot, I used "iris" dataset here as I can compared it against other data visualisation libraries. The current state I tried to create a SVG with an equal size for each category which I would use to contain box-plot. In other words, after I can create internal SVGs successfully, I will call a function to make the plot from there. Kinda same idea Mike did [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502).

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what you're intending, but from a glance, I'd guess that `.attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.key) })` does not work as intended, and should probably be something like `.attr('width', nestedWidth)`. It also looks like you're stacking transforms (with multiple calls to `xScale(d.key)`), which probably isn't intended either.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your input. It kinda worked but not yet where I wanted to go. Please see the update if it would give a clearer picture of what I intended to do.